# Add functioning SearchView to one specific Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, search, android-recyclerview

I got a fragment where I want to add a SearchView. I got it already in the Menu, its clickable and everything, but every guide I find to actually search something is either out of date or not exactly what I need.

This is my fragment

```
    class ViewFragment : Fragment () {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,container: ViewGroup?,
savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding: ViewFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.view_fragment, container, false)

        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)

        viewFragmentViewModel.navigateToEdit.observe(this, Observer {translation ->
            translation?.let {
                this.findNavController().navigate(
                    ViewFragmentDirections
                        .actionViewFragmentToEditFragment(translation)
                )
                viewFragmentViewModel.onEditNavigated()
            }
        })

        val adapter = TranslationAdapter(TranslationListener { translationID ->
            viewFragmentViewModel.onTranslationClicked(translationID)
        })
        binding.translationList.adapter = adapter

        viewFragmentViewModel.translations.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                adapter.submitList(it)
            }
        })

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)

    }
```

And this is my menu with the search

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get set everything up so I can access the search string the user has entered and submit a new list to the RecycleView? Or just point me in the right direction!

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Heres The update. I have an MutableLiveData Where i put the query and observe it so I can act on its observe function. I got a variable translationList in the ViewModel that I wanted to update.

```
class ViewFragment : Fragment (), SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {


private var searchText = MutableLiveData<String>()

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
```

...

```
    val adapter = TranslationAdapter(TranslationListener { translationID ->
        viewFragmentViewModel.onTranslationClicked(translationID)
    })
    binding.translationList.adapter = adapter

    viewFragmentViewModel.translations.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        it?.let {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        }
    })

    searchText.observe(this, Observer {searchString ->
        searchString?.let {
            if(searchString == ""){
                adapter.submitList(viewFragmentViewModel.translations.value)
            }
            else{
                adapter.submitList(viewFragmentViewModel.searchTranslations(searchString))
            }

        }
    })

}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)

    val menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
    val searchView = menuItem.actionView as SearchView
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}

override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {

    searchText.value = newText
    return true
}

override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
    return false
}
```

}

For the closure, since I already had an list with all my objects from the database I wanted to search in, its easier to just go through that list with a filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step - 1:** Implements `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` in your `ViewFragment`

```
class ViewFragment : Fragment(), SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    ...

    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {

        //Do your operation here

        return true
    }
}
```

**Step - 2:** Get `SearchView` from menu and initialize with listener

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)

    val meniItem = menu?.findItem(R.id.action_search)
    val searchView = meniItem?.actionView as SearchView?
    searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(this)

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}
```

**Step - 3:** Inside `onQueryTextChange` take your search query and do operation

**Update:** Change your implementation like below:

```
fun searchTranslations(searchString: String) : List<Translation>? {
    return database.getTranslationsBySearch(searchString).value
}
```

And Dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM word_translation_table WHERE word_ger LIKE '% :string %'  OR word_es LIKE '% :string %' ")
fun getTranslationsBySearch(string: String): LiveData<List<Translation>>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! This helped me a great deal. I can initiate a new Query that gets a new LiveData<List<Object>> from my database, but when I override the old LiveData object with the new one the screen doesnt get updated. Do you know why that could happen?

Comment: Need to check `viewFragmentViewModel.searchTranslations`. Also add this

Comment: I think i narrowed down the problem with the room database query.
Its just returning an empty list. Added the query to the question.

Comment: That doesnt work. "Unused parameter"
If I put '% :string %' there, it doesnt get the string. I tried similar things already.